# Best way to publicize instance attributes

Tags: python, class, attributes

I'm new to Python, coming from C#.  I know how to publicize class attributes and methods.  I'd like to publicize my instance variables.  Having intellisense detect them would be ideal.  Also, please let me know if this is not pythonic or if I should be doing something else.

```
class MyClass(Object):
    class_attribute = "Foo"

    #This is the way I'm currently publicizing instance attributes.  
    #Basically I'm using properties instead of instance attributes.
    @property
    def instance_property(self):
        return self._instance_property

    @instance_property.setter
    def instance_property_set(self, value):
        self._instance_property = value
```

Comment: this type of getter setter is discouraged in python ... why not just make the instance variable name `self.instance_property` instead of `self._instance_property`  and it should expose in any decent ide

Comment: Using properties like that is definitely *not* pythonic.  I don't know what intellisense likes however, so I can't give you much advice...

Comment: @JoranBeasley but how do consumers know they should populate `instance_property`?  Are they just supposed to know from documentation?

Comment: anything they SHOULDNT mess with should be prepended with one (or two underscores)  `_varname` is equivalent to a protected var (through convention) `__varname` is (conventionally) equivelent to a private var.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Right, I understand that consumers should know to not mess with `_varname`.  However, I don't understand how consumers should know to populate public instance variables.  Should this be done via arguments (and probably more nicely keyword arguments) in the `__init__` function?

Comment: @steaks If it's required, then yes - that's what constructors (in any language) are for...

Comment: often it is done in the init function ... or through documentation, or setting it to an invalid default value that you later check and inform consumer that they must set variable X before calling `Calculate()` or whatever ... getters and setters are not meant to inform a consumer what variables they should set

Comment: @JoranBeasley, this comment answers my question completely!  Would you mind adding this to your answer so I can accept?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyClass(Object):
    class_attribute = "Foo"

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.instance_property = "whatever"
```

often it(setting required values) is done in the init function ... or through documentation, or setting it to an invalid default value that you later check and inform consumer that they must set variable X before calling Calculate() or whatever ... getters and setters are not meant to inform a consumer what variables they should set

there is no reason to use getters/setters unless you actually need to do some work (not just pass it on to another variable)

a use case for a setter would be

```
class GPIO(object):
    @property
    def value(self):
        return open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio141/value").read()

    @value.setter
    def set_value(self,val):
         open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio141/value","w").write(val)
```

Comment: Ummm. Isn't that class property?

Comment: doesnt matter really ... but yeah ... (as soon as you refer to it as `self.instance_property` it effectivly becomes tied to the instance .. there I moved it into init

Comment: i think they did cause originally I had instance_property as a class var instead of settign it in init

Answer (score 3):

You are not required to do so. Python community uses [a convention](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) that any class member which name have:

- leading underscore - considered private/protected,
- double leading underscore considered  class private - mimics private access by using name mangling. Member is not accessible by it's name outside the class, as it's prefixed with class name (but still accessible if you directly call it)
- double leading underscore and double trailing underscore - overrides some behavior, closest C# analogue would be built-in interface implementations and overrides of `Object` methods. [More info in the docs.](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names)
- everything else considered public.

You can do properties, if you actually want to do some calculations upon acessing a member, but it's not considered/enforced as best practice.